# Backbone find and update model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, backbone-views

I am working with backbones and I have a collection with a few models. And I want to get a particular model and update it. I was able to do that with

```
var found = cuteyList.findWhere({"date" : post.date, "comment" : post.comment});
```

but I am unable to update it. When I do

```
found.set("date" : "2322");
```

It doesn't fire a change in the view.

in the view I have

```
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.movePostit);
},
```

How do I debug it or find out if the view is attached to the model? Still pretty new to backbones.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found out why, after using the chrome backbone debugger, I found out one of the views wasn't being created.